# Is it correct to take 0 out of the integral sign?

Tags: calculus

Why is the definite integral of 0 equal to 0 but its indefinite integral equal to an arbitrary constant C? Is it correct to take 0 out of the integral sign? But that way, the indefinite integral of 0 ends up being only 0 while it should be C.

Comment: The indefinite integral represents a family of functions: *all* functions whose antiderivative is $0$. The definite integral represents a *number*: the net signed area between the $x$ axis and the graph of the function on the given integral. **Nonzero** constants come out of the indefinite integral, but $0$ does not.

Comment: You can only take anti-derivatives of functions. By zero you mean the zero function, which isn't a constant number (a single number). You can only pull out constants. When we say that the anti-derivative of the zero (function) is a constant $C$ that $C$ is also a function. You can only take derivatives and anti-derivatives of functions, the result is also a function

Comment: Even better, the integral of the zero function is some specific constant function, say $7$, plus some true constant number $C$. But what is the constant function $7$, plus a number $C$? Just some new arbitrary constant function $c$

Answer (score 4):

The definite integral $\int_a^b0\,\mathrm dx$ can be computed as limit of Riemann sums, and already the individual Riemann sums are all zero, hence so is their limit.

The indefinite integral $\int0\,\mathrm dx$ is the general form of a function² whose derivative is the zero function. Apparently, every constant function fits.

---

² Strictly speaking, this is a *set* of functions and the common notation $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx=F(x)+C$ might be considered an abuse of notation. A formally more correct notation would be something like $\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\{\,F(x)+C\mid C\in\Bbb R\,\}$, but that is cumbersome (and confusing). On the other hand, the common notation may also turn out to be confusing as soon as several integration constants come into play ...

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative
$$\int f(x)dx  = F(x) \iff F'(x) = f(x)$$
so it isn't unique. Per Newton-Leibniz formula ($f$ assumed to be continuous in $[a,b]$)
$$\int _a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a) $$
As the antiderivative of $0$ is any constant (constant function)  we would have
$$\int _a^b 0dx = C(b) - C(a) = 0. $$